# Where to put the extension methods(loaded only once) in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, extension-methods

I have couple of helper methods added to the existing classes, and i want them to be loaded only once. for example i have a except method

```
class Array
  def except(array)
    self.select do |item|
      array.exclude? item
    end
  end
end
```

and would like to call it from different views & controllers like this

```
 a= [1,2,3,4]
 b=a.except [1,3]
```

Comment: you might want to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842359/extending-core-ruby-classes-when-in-rails

Comment: thanks dude, thats what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into a file in config/initializers. These are loaded in alphabetic order; so if some other code uses it during initialisation, just use a file like config/initializers/000_important_monkey_patches.rb